# Getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while fetching the row count from each table in the database

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am working on a Java-Jdbc program which will take the row count of all the tables present in the database. To do that, I came up with the following code:

```
// Get the source(gp) count
public Map<String,Long> getGpTableCount() throws SQLException {
    Map<String, String> gpTableMap = getScopeTableList();   // Key: Sourceschema.tablename, value: Destschema.tablename:sourcesystem1,sourcesystem2...sourcesystemn
    Set<String> gpTableSet = gpTableMap.keySet();           // Gets the Source Table names - Schema.Tablename
    gpCountMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    Iterator<String> keySetIterator_gpTables = gpTableSet.iterator();
    Connection gpAnalyticsCon = (Connection) DbManager.getGpConnection();
    while(keySetIterator_gpTables.hasNext()) {
        //getting source system names
        String gpTabSchemakey = keySetIterator_gpTables.next();
        String tablesnSSNs = gpTableMap.get(gpTabSchemakey);
        String[] ssnArray = tablesnSSNs.split(":");
        String sourceSystems = ssnArray[1];
        System.out.println(sourceSystems);
        if(sourceSystems.equals("No_SSNs_available") || sourceSystems == "No_SSNs_available") {
            System.out.println("In the if condition");
            gptableCountWithoutSsn = tblCountWithoutSsn(gpTabSchemakey, gpAnalyticsCon);
            gpTabMapWoSsn.put(gpTabSchemakey, gptableCountWithoutSsn);
        } else {
            System.out.println("In the else condition");
            //get the source system names
            String inSourceSystems = "('" + sourceSystems.replace(",", "','") + "')";
            String gpSchemaTableName = gpTabSchemakey;
            String[] gpparts = gpSchemaTableName.split("\\.");  // schema, tablename
            String gpTable = gpparts[1];
            String gpCountQuery = "select '" + gpTable + "' as TableName, count(*) as Count, source_system_name from " + gpSchemaTableName + " where source_system_name in " + inSourceSystems +" group by source_system_name order by source_system_name";
            // resultSet(1): TableName, resultSet(2): count, resultSet(3): source_system_name
            try {
                PreparedStatement gp_pstmnt = gpAnalyticsCon.prepareStatement(gpCountQuery);
                ResultSet gpCountRs = gp_pstmnt.executeQuery();
                while(gpCountRs.next()) {
                    System.out.println("Tablename: " + gpCountRs.getString(1) + " Source System Name: " + gpCountRs.getString(3) + ", Count: " + gpCountRs.getLong(2));
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    ssn = getSsn(gpCountRs.getString(3));
                    gpCountMap.put(gpTable + ": " + gpCountRs.getString(3), gpCountRs.getLong(2));
                }
            } catch(org.postgresql.util.PSQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Table: " + gpTable + " not found for the source system: " + ssn);
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    gpAnalyticsCon.close();
    return gpCountMap;
}
```

There are two kinds of tables in the code.

1. Tables that have source systems
2. Tables without any source systems

There is an if-else condition where tables without sourcesystem names go to 'if' and those have source systems, go to 'else' condition.
In the 'if', I am calling another method: `tblCountWithoutSsn` which is written as:

```
// Method that returns the row count of tables without any source system name
private Long tblCountWithoutSsn(String tableWithoutSsn, Connection con) throws SQLException {
    String[] woSsn = tableWithoutSsn.split("\\.");
    long count=0;
    String tablename = woSsn[1];
    String query = "select '" + tablename + "' as TableName, count(*) as count from " + tableWithoutSsn;    
    System.out.println("Executing table: " + tablename + " which doesn't have any source system name");
    System.out.println("Query for tables with no source_systems: " + query);
    PreparedStatement gpwoSsn_pstmnt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = gpwoSsn_pstmnt.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
        count = rs.getLong(2);
    }
    System.out.println("TableName: " + tablename + ", count: " + count);
    return count;
}
```

There are 41 tables without any source systems. When I execute the jar file, I could see the count such of tables:

```
In the if condition
Executing table: table1withoutSSN which doesn't have any source system name
Query for tables with no source_systems: select 'table1withoutSSN' as TableName, count(*) as count from analytics_view.table1withoutSSN
TableName: table1withoutSSN, count: 1764

In the if condition
Executing table: table2withoutSSN which doesn't have any source system name
Query for tables with no source_systems: select 'table2withoutSSN' as TableName, count(*) as count from ge_hr3.table2withoutSSN
TableName: table2withoutSSN, count: 473376
```

But as soon as it reaches the table: table3WithoutSSN the code give exception and connection closes. The exception can be seen below:

```
In the if condition
Executing table: table3WithoutSSN which doesn't have any source system name
Query for tables with no source_systems: select 'table3WithoutSSN' as TableName, count(*) as count from custSchema.table3WithoutSSN
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:803)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.prepareStatement(PgConnection.java:1621)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.prepareStatement(PgConnection.java:415)
        at com.recordcount.dao.GpHiveRecords.tblCountWithoutSsn(GpHiveRecords.java:156)
        at com.recordcount.dao.GpHiveRecords.getGpTableCount(GpHiveRecords.java:72)
        at com.recordcount.entry.StartCount.main(StartCount.java:12)
        ... 5 more
```

The line 156 in the exception is:

```
PreparedStatement gpwoSsn_pstmnt = con.prepareStatement(query); from the method: `tblCountWithoutSsn`
```

Connection method in DBManager Class:

```
private static Connection gpAnalyticsConnection = null; // Creating gp connection
public static Connection getGpConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        if(gpAnalyticsConnection == null) {
            gpAnalyticsConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("hostname", "username", "password");
            return gpAnalyticsConnection;
        } else {
        return gpAnalyticsConnection;
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here and how can I rectify that.

Comment: "Connection closed" usually means some sort of networking issue.  Look at your network.

Comment: What part of _"Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed."_ is unclear? And contrary to the previous commenter, I think this problem usually occurs when the connection was already closed in your code. And the fact that you use some handcrafted class called `DbManager` to manage your connections, makes me think that you might be sharing the same connection on multiple threads (and the other thread closed it), or at minimum don't correctly validate connections.

Comment: @markspace This exception occurs particularly for that table & I have executed the code 4 times and exactly for that table, the code is giving the exception.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel As you can see, the connection.close() statement is put outside the while loop where the iteration of several table names happen.

Comment: Please show the code of that `DbManager` class. I think you are trying to reuse a connection that was already closed by another part of your program. The exception is crystal clear: you're using a connection that has been closed.

Comment: Added the connection part of the code.

Comment: The code as shown proves my theory. What do you think happens when you use `DbManager.getGpConnection()`, use the connection and close it, and then call `DbManager.getGpConnection()` again and try to use the connection? (hint: it is exactly the problem described in your question, as you will be trying to use a connection that has been closed) Stop using that `DbManager`, and starting using a proper connection pool library.